# How to run every 3 minute in Quartz scheduler?

Tags: c#, scheduling, jobs, quartz.net

I am using the Quartz Scheduling API for C#. Could you help me to run every 3 minute using cron-expression.
I cannot find an expression which lets me run my job from 8:45 to 17:15 every 3 minute
Does anybody know any way to do this expression?
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quartz.Net cron trigger to schedule a job every 45 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330578/quartz-net-cron-trigger-to-schedule-a-job-every-45-minutes)

Answer (score 1):

```
 ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
               .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
                 (s =>
                    s.WithIntervalInHours(24)
                   .OnEveryDay()
                   .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(8, 45))
                   .WithIntervalInMinutes(3)
                   .EndingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(17, 15))
                 )
               .Build();
```